# Idris interactive environment doesn't work properly

Tags: haskell, idris

I've downloaded Idris using Windows binary available at https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev (https://neon.se/idris/idris-1.1.1-win32.exe)
It is claimed that "It includes everything needed to run Idris and build Idris programs, including a toolchain for the C backend. "
I had no problem with compiling .idr source files but when I try to evaluate simple expressions using REPL, the program dies with an error. The message box says that running idris.exe is terminated and Windows tries to recover error.[image: message box]
I'm running 32-bit Windows 7.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: The crash details would be helpful. As a wild guess, your CPU might just be missing some instructions GHC assumed as existing.

Comment: Wait a bit for Windows to complete that search, and then take a look at crash info. There would be at least module name that caused crash.

Comment: @arrowd, according to crash info, there is an incorrect pathway: C:\idris\idris.exe, problem name is APPCRASH, module name is ntdll.dll, exception code is c0000005. Unfortunately, this doesn't tell me much.

Comment: You should probably move that discussion to [Idris' bugtracker](https://github.com/idris-lang/idris-dev/issues).

Comment: I've got an older version and everything runs o'k.